# Python logging: reverse effects of disable()

Tags: python, logging

The [logging docs](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.disable) say that calling the `logging.disable(lvl)` method can "temporarily throttle logging output down across the whole application," but I'm having trouble finding the "temporarily." Take, for example, the following script:

```
import logging
logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)
logging.warning("test")
# Something here
logging.warning("test")
```

So far, I haven't been able to find the `Something here` that will re-enable the logging system as a whole and allow the second `warning` to get through. Is there a reverse to `disable()`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)
```

Comment: Fantastic, and - in retrospect - pretty obvious :) Thanks!

Comment: Any way to contact python documentation team? Something is obviously missing there.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer by @unutbu, I created a context manager:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class SuppressLogging:
    """
    Context handler class that suppresses logging for some controlled code.
    """

    def __init__(self, loglevel):
        logging.disable(loglevel)
        return

    def __enter__(self):
        return 

    def __exit__(self, exctype, excval, exctraceback):
        logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    log.info("log this")
    with SuppressLogging(logging.WARNING):
        log.info("don't log this")
        log.warning("don't log this warning")
        log.error("log this error while up to WARNING suppressed")
    log.info("log this again")
```