# How to undo a logging.disable() command in logging module in Python?

Tags: python, logging

In the powerful logging built-in module in Python, it is possible to disable all logs below a level by calling, for example, `logging.disable(logging.INFO)`.

I did not find how to reset or undo this setting in the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html).

My purpose is to disable and re-enable info and debugging level logs when doing unittests, by calling logging.disable in `setUp()`, then calling (what?) in `tearDown()`.

NB: I know how to do it if I have a give `logger` instance: keep `logger.level`, set the level higher, then set it back in `tearDown()`. I would prefer a way to mute all loggers without choosing them explicitly.

Comment: have you tried calling logging.disable() again with a higher logging level?

Comment: @MikeCorcoran this would disable even more logs. I could try to disable(logging.DEBUG) but this would mute debug messages.

Comment: try passing zero to logging.disable()

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like the answer is to call logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('testlog')
handler = logging.FileHandler('\\path\\to\\testlog.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.error("some error occurred")
logger.info('some info msg')
logging.disable(logging.ERROR)
logger.info('another info msg')
logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)
logger.info('last info msg')
```

results in a log file with this output:

```
2012-05-17 11:09:24,441 ERROR some error occurred
2012-05-17 11:09:24,443 INFO some info msg
2012-05-17 11:09:24,443 INFO last info msg
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems this info is missing from the documentation.

Comment: I edited the answer to use the constant logging.NOTSET instead of magical "0".

Comment: In fact my question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948190/python-logging-reverse-effects-of-disable which has the correct answer. Didn't find any "mark as dupe" button, maybe I don't have enough karma or badges...

Comment: For info, I submitted a doc bug to bugs.python.org and it was fixed in less than one hour, so next time someone has the issue we probably can redirect to official documentation.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118124/where-on-earth-is-the-mark-as-duplicate-ui-on-stack-overflow for flagging as duplicate